# Use python to make Box A smaller than Box B by fixed number?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script that will make Box A smaller than Box B in dimensions by a fixed number. I started off by making Box A the same size as box B with the script below.

My issue is that I can't seem to make the dimensions of Box A equal to the size of Box B minus e. g 1. If I use x-1,y-1 for my new size for o.dimensions, both boxes are affected and both seem to become some median size of the two.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

for o in context.selected_objects:

    x = context.object.dimensions.x

    y = context.object.dimensions.y

    z = context.object.dimensions.z

    o.dimensions = [x,y,z]

    o.location = context.object.location
```

Comment: You would want to multiply with a factor rather than subtract, otherwise what would you do if your object has dimensions between below 1?

Comment: Also the `bpy.context.object` is also in `bpy.context.selected_objects` so you would also change the dimensions of the object you're using as reference

Comment: Thanks rjg, you're right, I've changed my code to *0.95 for each axis to make the second box 95% the size of the first. Works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.object` is also part of the `context.selected_objects` collection.

So here's what you can do:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

objs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o != context.object]
for o in objs:

    x = context.object.dimensions.x

    y = context.object.dimensions.y

    z = context.object.dimensions.z

    o.dimensions = [x,y,z]

    o.location = context.object.location
```